# How to pass Json data to another screen in flutter

Tags: json, dart, flutter

```
List results;      
setState(() {
          var resBody = json.decode(res.body);
          print('Response body: ${resBody}');
          results = resBody;
        });
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => SecondScreen(jsondata: results,),
            ));
```

**results is a jsondata and pass it to the second screen as jsondata**

**In secondscreen how to retrieve jsondata ?**

Comment: You passed it to the constructor.

Comment: You are already passing it, I don't see what's the problem ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you. Let me know

```
class SecondScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  final List jsondata;

  SecondScreen({Key key, this.jsondata}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SecondScreenState createState() => _SecondScreenState();
}

class _SecondScreenState extends State<SecondScreen> {

    // use jsondata here in widget here like this,
**widget.jsondata**

}
```

Comment: [primo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8101634/primo)  thanks it's works

Answer (score 0):

You can store JsonData “state” in a model class and use it in the other screen.