# How to pass Json data to multi screen in flutter

Tags: android, json, api, flutter, dart

I can pass data to a widget like this:
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55956470/how-to-pass-json-data-to-another-screen-in-flutter)
But for multi widgets I don't know what to do?

Comment: What do you mean with multi widgets? Can you provide a code example to better understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use state mangment like block pattern or provider consumer with model of you json object and put all widget inside single parent